# APK for all android devices

Tags: android, apk, wear-os

From Android wear to the Nexus 5 to Android TV, is it possible to publish only **one** APK to the Play Store and expect it to work on all devices, particularly the wearable devices?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, done carefully, and taking into account that if you want a dedicate Wear app (versus just notification), that the Wear app is *embedded* in the main app for mobile devices.

Comment: In order for that to happen, do I need a wearable module in the same project? Or, could I somehow create a layout resource directory (based on dp) for Android wear as well as devices like the QVGA that's not as high in density?

Comment: "do I need a wearable module in the same project?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: CommonsWare is correct. You need a separate module in your project for the wearable app, because it's actually a separate app that will be embedded within the APK you upload to the Play Store. That's the only way to get it to install to Wear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All the Android platform devices can work with the same APK.

**Smartphones and tablets:** Trivial.

**TVs:** You need to create at least one [launcher activity  designed for television](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/tv/start/start.html):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

**Wearables:** You create a [new module for the wearable app](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) that goes in the same apk of the main app, telling to Gradle that it is a wearable app:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+''
   wearApp project(':wearable')
}
```

**Auto:** For Android Auto, can't create an Activity for that, instead, you send messages with the provided APIs. However, [you need to set in your manifest that you have Auto features](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/auto/start/index.html):

```
<application>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
     android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
</application>
```

If you want to learn more about these devices and how to develop for them, [check the Android courses on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android).

Comment: Not sure if the Udacity link is really relevant to the answer; it seems biased to include it.

Comment: So I presume that I need to create a new project with Android Studio as opposed to working on an existing project (handheld app module) if I wanted to include both modules in one APK, correct?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, just right click in your current module:
New > Module (or File > New > New Module...). It will ask what type of module you want, so you can create a wearable module and the IDE will set everything for you.